# Retrieve elements from iText Document object

Tags: dom, itext

I am trying to write some tests for PDF files and rather than testing the binary output of a cached PDF against one that has just been generated I am looking into generating the Document and then examining it against a set of known parameters such as positions.

The version of `itext` that is being used is 7.0.0.

Is it possible to retrieve all of this information from the `Document` object? I can see that the Document has a `childElements` object which I cannot access as it is protected.

As an example, there is a iText div added which I would like to retrieve and then extract the positioning values from it.

```
public class Address extends Div
{
    public Address()
    {
      final Paragraph address = new Paragraph(              
                    "Address 1\n" +
                    "Address 2\n");

      address.setMarginTop(top);

      add(address);
    }
}

Document document;

document.add(new Address());
```

I have tried to keep the example as concise as possible without adding in unneccessary code as the there is a lot of code to build the PDF.

What I would like to achieve is to retrieve information from the Address div such as the margin top value using the document object.

Comment: _"I think that the version of itextpdf that is being used is 5.1.1 and the layout library the project is using is layout-7.0.0."_ - iText 5.1.1 and layout-7.0.0 (part of iText 7.0.0) are not compatible. If you are using Maven, can you add the output of `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose` to your question?

Comment: _rather than testing the binary output of a cached PDF against one that has just been generated_ - good idea! Take a look at the source code of iText's CompareTool to see how we do it. You can find the source code on GitHub: https://github.com/itext/itext7/blob/develop/kernel/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/kernel/utils/CompareTool.java

Comment: Is the main iText jar now called kernel-7.0.0? It looks like itextpdf-5.1.1.jar is on the classpath but so are kernel-7.0.0, io-7.0.0 and layout-7.0.0.

Comment: iText 5 was one monolithic jar. iText 7 is modular, with kernel, io, layout being some of the essential modules. See  https://developers.itextpdf.com/itext7/download-and-install-information/Java

Comment: So this means that you have both iText 5 and iText 7 on your classpath. While in theory this may work, it could lead to confusing situations, so I strongly recommend against it.

Comment: Thank you for the information and the link to the github page this is exactly what I need! I have not used iText for a long time and I am currently investigating why both are on the classpath as it doesnt look like the itext5 jar is being used by any classes.

Comment: I suggest that you first get clarity about the iText version you use, then edit your question with the exact version. Once you have done that, I propose to delete this comment thread, because it distracts from your actual question (which I won't be able to answer at this time, but someone else might).

Comment: @berimbolo iText does not hold an object model of everything you added to a document in memory; on the contrary, it attempts to free objects in memory as soon as possible by writing them to the result stream. Thus, you will only find your `Address` DIV in the document until it is layout'ed. What you can try, though, is reading the finished PDF into a `PdfReader` and `PdfDocument` and apply text extraction.